# Joining multiple subqueries

Tags: postgresql, join, self-join

I need a query that returns something in this format:

```
pk  id  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
----------------------
...
pk1 id1 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
pk6 id2 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
...
```

My current data looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE foo(pk,id,value)
AS VALUES
    ( 'pk1' , 'id1',  'A1' ),
    ( 'pk2' , 'id1',  'A2' ),
    ( 'pk3' , 'id1',  'A3' ),
    ( 'pk4' , 'id1',  'A4' ),
    ( 'pk5' , 'id1',  'A5' ),
    ( 'pk6' , 'id2',  'B1' ),
    ( 'pk7' , 'id2',  'B2' ),
    ( 'pk8' , 'id2',  'B3' ),
    ( 'pk9' , 'id2',  'B4' ),
    ( 'pk10', 'id2',  'B5' )
;
```

The source table has ~160,000,000 rows. All columns are indexed (btree).

Currently I'm doing 5 (the real number is dynamic and maybe around 30, but for example above it's 5) different queries to extract:

1:

```
P1 id1 A1
P6 id2 B1
```

2:

```
P2 id1 A2
P7 id2 B2
```

3:

```
P3 id1 A3
P8 id2 B4
```

etc

and then join these queries. Something like this:

```
SELECT q1.pk,q1.id,q1.v1,q2.v2,q3.v3,q4.v4,q5.v5 FROM (SELECT pk, id, value FROM table WHERE id=1) AS q1, (SELECT pk, id, value FROM table WHERE id=2) AS q2, (SELECT pk, id, value FROM table WHERE id=3) AS q3, (SELECT pk, id, value FROM table WHERE id=4) AS q4, (SELECT pk, id, value FROM table WHERE id=5) AS q5 WHERE q1.id=q2.id and q2.id=q3.id and q3.id=q4.id and q4.id=q5.id;
```

But as I mentioned above number of joins are much more (~30) and it runs really slow on Postgres. I examined the planning and disabled `nestloop` and it got much faster but it's still too slow. If I fetch all these queries to memory and join them programmatically (using python for example) it runs in ~1 second. But Postgres takes too long (~30 seconds for joining 110 rows).
Any ideas? I think there must be a better way than making 30 subqueries and joining them. Another approach would be grouping rows based on `id` column and do some magic (for example with `RowNumber()`) to generate the desired table.

P.S. It's not applicable to pre-generate the result table. Everything must happen runtime.

Comment: How are you picking `pk1` and `pk6` in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, all you want is

```
SELECT
  min(pk),
  id,
  array_agg(value ORDER BY value)
FROM foo
GROUP BY id;

 min  | id  |    array_agg     
------+-----+------------------
 pk1  | id1 | {A1,A2,A3,A4,A5}
 pk10 | id2 | {B1,B2,B3,B4,B5}
(2 rows)
```

If you need the `array_agg` to be unwrapped, you can do,

```
SELECT pk, id, a[1] AS v1, a[2] AS v2, a[3] AS v3, a[4] AS v4, a[5] AS v5
FROM (
  SELECT
    min(pk),
    id,
    array_agg(value ORDER BY value)
  FROM foo
  GROUP BY id
) AS t(pk, id, a);

  pk  | id  | v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 | v5 
------+-----+----+----+----+----+----
 pk1  | id1 | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5
 pk10 | id2 | B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | B5
```

**Note, in all future examples please don't use `id1` and `pk1`. You're sample values should preferably be just `1` and `2`. As you can see here, we're struggling with getting `pk10` instead of `pk6` and that's a problem only because of the sort order.**